# PowerShell output without function

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I try to write a PowerShell Script, but everytime I run it I get some output although I don't use a function which generates any output.

This is my code:

```
$givenName = @()

Import-Csv -Path H:\test2.csv -Delimiter ";"
ForEach-Object {
    $givenName = $_.name.split()[0]
}
```

Output:

```
Name         Phone Number
----         ------------
Peter Maier  123123
Paul Paulsen 465456
```

Comment: `Import-CSV`'s output is neither piped nor assigned into a variable, so as a last result, Powershell will write it on console.

Comment: @vonPryz Thank you. I'm very new to PowerShell... I Just added a | after my delimiter so it's piped